# html code where javascript is expected (browser js debugger)

Tags: javascript, html

See the attached image for details. When opening a page with Firefox javascript debugger and clicking on one of the source files it shows HTML code instead of javascript, which I would normally expect there.

Does it mean that some `<script>` tag on the page links to an html file instead of javascript? If yes, then for what purpose?

[image]

Comment: Please don't just downvote silently. Explain the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Surely because the HTML file contains a `script` element, at the bottom of your img.

Comment: If you mean `odesk.pageConfig.companyRef = 'd7114896'` then it just sets a variable. It doesn't link to an external file.